# UberMenu options screen doesn't work at menu setup

Tags: wordpress, plugins, megamenu

I just purchased and installed UberMenu plugin version v3.2.1.1, followed the setup exactly the way they described, and I'm able to see the Ubermenu instance in my front page, as it should be.

However, I can't access the customization area of the menu, and therefore I can't tweak it my own way.

When I go to **Appearance** -> **Menus** and click on the **Uber button** on any menu item, all I get is an empty options popup, just like the image below. None of the tabs present any content, it's just like the plugin scripts weren't being loaded. 
However I see that blue popup in the lower right end of the screen saying it was being loaded correctly, and it's gone properly when it ends the job.

[image: blank configuration screen]
What can I do to enable/load correctly the configuration options for this plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: the plugin page is the place to ask general q's. I think they actually have a dedicated support page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally 2 possibilities that can make this happen:

1. A PHP error occurs (for example, a memory limit exception), preventing the page from loading the content critical to the menu item settings panel.  You can check if that's the case by viewing your Menus Panel page source and seeing if you have a closing HTML tag.

or

2. The theme alters the admin menu structure via a custom Walker, resulting in the plugin not being able to find the appropriate data within the admin menu items to generate the settings panel.  This is not very common, but can happen with themes that offer their own custom menu item settings within the Appearance > Menus Panel, as they alter the standard item markup to suit their needs.

If you need assistance, just **[Submit a Support Ticket](http://sevenspark.com/help)** over at sevenspark.com and we'll help you get it sorted out :)

Have a great weekend!

Comment: Thanks Chris!I just created a ticket at your support channel.